# System.out.println() output to TextArea

Tags: android, textarea

I have a question, how to redirect the `System.out.println()` output that in array form into TextArea in my Eclipse project's interface?.

**Im using The Princeton FFT algorithm** in java that the result of the formula come out using the `System.out.println()` method.
Here the code:

```
public class FFT {
// compute the FFT of x[], assuming its length is a power of 2
public static Complex[] fft(Complex[] x) {
    int N = x.length;

    // base case
    if (N == 1) return new Complex[] { x[0] };

    // radix 2 Cooley-Tukey FFT
    if (N % 2 != 0) { throw new RuntimeException("N is not a power of 2"); }

    // fft of even terms
    Complex[] even = new Complex[N/2];
    for (int k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
        even[k] = x[2*k];
    }
    Complex[] q = fft(even);

    // fft of odd terms
    Complex[] odd  = even;  // reuse the array
    for (int k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
        odd[k] = x[2*k + 1];
    }
    Complex[] r = fft(odd);

    // combine
    Complex[] y = new Complex[N];
    for (int k = 0; k < N/2; k++) {
        double kth = -2 * k * Math.PI / N;
        Complex wk = new Complex(Math.cos(kth), Math.sin(kth));
        y[k]       = q[k].plus(wk.times(r[k]));
        y[k + N/2] = q[k].minus(wk.times(r[k]));
    }
    return y;
}

// display an array of Complex numbers to standard output
public static void show(Complex[] x, String title) {
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    for (Complex x1 : x) {
       System.out.println(x1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int N = Integer.parseInt("4");
    Complex[] x = new Complex[N];

    // original data
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = new Complex(i, 0);
        x[i] = new Complex(-2*Math.random() + 1, 0);
    }
    show(x, "x");

    // FFT of original data
    Complex[] y = fft(x);
    show(y, "y = fft(x)");

    // take inverse FFT
    Complex[] z = ifft(y);
    show(z, "z = ifft(y)");

}
}
```

I want to change the `System.out.println()` in `show()` method.
Please help, thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to Log the output in Android Logcat?

Comment: i have run it in Netbeans and it shows some values in it's console, i want to bring that value to my TextArea in the eclipse, but till now i cant, i've try  to change the show() method, but it still the same